# Quarkus GraphQL using Hibernate

Tags: graphql, quarkus, jpastreamer

I am creating a Quarkus GraphQL using JPAStreamer, I would like to fetch only what I indicated in my query (by the way I'm using sakila database).

Here's the result.

[image]

Upon logging the result in sql. it display this SQL statement, I only want description be queried in database. Is there any way for that?

[image]

Sample Code:

```
@GraphQLApi
public class CharacterQuery {

    @Inject
    JPAStreamer jpaStreamer;

    @Query
    @Description("Create a film")
    public List<Film> fetchAllCharacters(@Name("size") Long size) {
        List<Film> data = jpaStreamer.stream(
                Projection.select(Film$.filmId,Film$.description, Film$.title) // Is there any way to fetch the query and pass here?
        ).limit(size).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Log.info(String.format("DATA RECIEVED: %s", new Gson().toJson(data)));


        return data;
    }



}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "film", schema = "sakila")
@Setter
@Getter
public class Film {

    Film(){}

    public Film(short filmId, String title, String description) {
        this.filmId = filmId;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }


    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "film_id")
    private short filmId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```